# NSTextField Color issues

Tags: objective-c, nstextfield

I am dynamically adding a `NSTextField` to a window and I am having issues with rendering. I am setting the background color to be black and the text color to be white. These both work but their is what appears to be a rectangle that is part of the text that is always white. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? How can I get rid of the white background that is just around the text? Code is as follows:

```
//Create rectangle to size text field

NSRect textFieldRect = NSMakeRect(300, 300, 300, 54);

//Instantiate text field and set defaults
NSTextField* textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:textFieldRect];

[textField setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:48]];

[textField setTextColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];

[textField setStringValue:@"Some Text"];

[textField setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blackColor]];

[textField setDrawsBackground:YES];

[textField setBordered:NO];

[[window contentView] addSubview:textField];
```

Answer (score 11):

I tried your code on Mac OS X 10.6.4.

Inside the application delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSRect textFieldRect = NSMakeRect(300, 300, 300, 54);
    NSTextField* textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:textFieldRect];
    [textField setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:48]];
    [textField setTextColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
    [textField setStringValue:@"Some Text"];
    [textField setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
    [textField setDrawsBackground:YES];
    [textField setBordered:NO];
    [[window contentView] addSubview:textField];
}
```

And this is the result

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/26c04b6b64.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/26c04b6b64.png)

I can't see any white box.
Maybe you are using a different OS.
Or maybe you have some other views on top of each other that are causing the weird effect you are talking about.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Florin, maybe something that is important, I am adding the NSTextField to a dynamically created NSWindow that has a black background. Not sure if that makes a difference but it must considering you don't seem to be having the same problem I am.

Comment: link is broken. Why have you not uploaded it to SO?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `refusesFirstResponder = TRUE` property of your NSTextField object. I have come across behavior you described in 10.7, in 10.6 everything works as expected.

Comment: makes no difference for me on Sierra

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

The mystery is partially solved. In conjunction with my NSTextField, I am also setting some NSApplicationPresentationOptions to put the application into Kiosk mode. It appears that something with that is causing the problem I am seeing. If I do not set the PresentationOptions the NSTextField displays exactly the way I want it to. I will track down what specific PresentationOption is to blame and post here.

Comment: It appears that the call to
 
[NSApp setPresentationOptions: ]

is to blame. Even if I call it setting it to the default, it will cause the text to have a white background. Hmm.....